# Auto snooze local notifications in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, uilocalnotification

I am developing an application in which I want to snooze the received notification automatically for 10 mins, if user didn't take any action (neither dismiss notification, nor opened the app) on the previously displayed notification. This is required in iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. Have you ever seen an app behave that way? No, because it's impossible (and incoherent).

Think of it this way. If the user does nothing, your app gets no signal that the notification fired. So it cannot "do" anything in response. You cannot respond to something that didn't happen.

Here's another way to look at it. When the notification fires, your app might not even be running. If the user does nothing, your app *still* won't be running. So how can it "do" anything?

---

In a comment, you referenced an app that has an "autosnooze" feature. But that app likely isn't snoozing *in response* to the fact that the user didn't do anything. It is scheduling a repeating notification (or multiple notifications) *in advance*, so the repetitions are *already* present when the user does nothing. When the user *does* respond, the app *deletes* the extra scheduled notifications. So you see, as I said before, the app responds to something that the user *did* do, not to something the user *didn't* do (though I can see why this behavior might give the illusion that it does what you asked to do).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here I was taking reference of "aida wake up alarm" which has auto snooze feature:
Auto-Snooze: Automatically repeat the alarm up to 5 times at regular intervals (e.g. 1 min, 5 mins, 10 mins) until you take action.

Comment: Ah, but it probably isn't snoozing _in response_ to the fact that the user didn't do anything. It is scheduling a repeating notification (or multiple notifications), so they are _already_ present when the user does nothing. When the user _does_ respond, the app _deletes_ the extra scheduled notifications. That's very different from what you asked to do (though I can see why this behavior might give the _illusion_ that it does what you asked to do). — I'll add this to my answer.